# Can a spellcaster use Wild Arcana/Inspired Spell to craft scrolls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The Mythic path ability [Wild Arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/archmage) (and the divine equivalent, [Inspired Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths---paizo-inc/hierophant)) let you cast any spell on your class list, without having to know that spell.  Can a crafter with one of these abilities use the mythic power to craft a scroll (or potion, or staff) for a spell that they don't know?  Typically, you need to have a spell prepared or known to create a scroll, but can the ability to cast spells that you don't know let you create scrolls?

I'd much prefer RAW answers.  Personally, I'd allow this, but my GM disagrees, and I'd like a RAW argument one way or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The RAW is pretty clear on this, you don't need to actually be able to cast the spell yourself via the usual method of being a spellcaster with the spell known, preparing it if not a spontaneous caster, and then expending the slot. All that is required is that you have [*access*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) to the spell, in that you have to have some way to arrange for an instance of it to be cast into the item once per day while the item is being worked on. The book specifically calls out options like scrolls, wands, wondrous items that cast the spell in question, and having another caster drop by once a day to cast the spell. It'd be rather hard to justify any of those if the Mythic option you describe, which is much closer to the usual method than any of those, were disallowed.

Comment: Could you provide supporting quotes from the book as well?  I agree with you, I just think I'll have more success convincing my GM with rules quotes.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl I linked them to the word "access". The most relevant sentence is the third one in the second paragraph of the linked section, "Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item's creator (although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed)."

Answer (score -1):

### No

The [creating scroll](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Scrolls) text says:

> The **creator** must have prepared the spell to be scribed (or must know
>   the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard)

All others types of magic objects, except rings, share the same requirement. Also, there is the following  text in the same page, concerning magic item construction requeriments:

> A spell prerequisite may be provided by a character who has prepared
>   the spell (or who knows the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard),
>   or through the use of a spell completion or spell trigger magic item
>   or a spell-like ability that produces the desired spell effect. For
>   each day that passes in the creation process, the creator must expend
>   one spell completion item or one charge from a spell trigger item if
>   either of those objects is used to supply a prerequisite.

Both Wild arcana and Inspired Spell let you cast any spell in you class spell list even if you do not have it prepared or (if you are a spontaneous spell caster) know it. They do not grant knowledge of the spell or allow you to prepare it, they just allow you to cast the spell as if you had.

Most specific item creation rules (except rings) require the **creator** to  *specifically* to have prepared/know the spell, as opposed to just being able to cast it. These rules do not concern with the source of the spells required to actually craft the item, only  with the spells that the creator has prepared/known.

Also,the general rules of magic item creation says that the item spells requirements must be satisfied by a character that have prepared/know that spell(or have access to it from an item/sp ability). But those mythic abilities are not spell-like abilities, nor spell completion or spell trigger magic item, and they do not allow a caster to have prepared/know spells she does normally not have (just to cast any spell as if she had).

In conclusion, neither Wild arcana nor Inspired Spell those abilities automatically allow you to create magical items you would not otherwise be qualified to create. Also, note that while potions, spell-trigger, or spell-completion magic items cannot be created without meeting its prerequisites, the rest of items, like magic weapons, can. The creator just get a + 5 to DC of crafting the item each requirement not meet.

Of course, Magic Item creation rules were written way before Mythic adventures rules, so it is more than possible that what you propose is not covered by the rules just because there is not (and probably will never exist) an official revision of the old rules taking into account the new material. But that falls into DM decision territory.

Comment: The part about spell like abilities is on the paragraph explaining magic item Requirements.Inside the section about magic item descriptions.

Comment: Ah. Apparently they really scattered the rules for this to the four winds throughout the book. And a different set of rules everywhere it appears. So, basically, the RAW is "do whatever you like, somewhere's a page that supports you".